# Proving that $b=infV\Leftrightarrow\epsilon>0, [b,b+\epsilon[\cap V \neq \emptyset$

Tags: analysis

Question:
We observe a not empty subset $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ and an lower bound b of $V$.
Prove that the folowing are equivalent:

(a) b=infV

(b) for each $\epsilon>0, [b,b+\epsilon[\cap V \neq \emptyset$

Proof:
$b=infV\Rightarrow\forall\epsilon>0, [b,b+\epsilon[\cap V \neq \emptyset$.

Because b=infV: $\exists s\in V$ with $s<b+\epsilon$ and with $s\leq b$ thus
$s\in [b,b+\epsilon[\Rightarrow V\bigcap B(b,\epsilon)\neq \emptyset\Rightarrow [b,b+\epsilon[\cap V$.

Now I need to prove that $\forall\epsilon>0, [b,b+\epsilon[\cap V \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow b=infV$. How do I do this?

Comment: How do you say that $b\in V$? Is it given to you that $b\in V$?

Comment: No it is not I assumed it

Comment: How can you assume it? Say $V=[0,1],\ b=-1$, then $b$ is a lower bound of $V$ but $b\notin V$.

Comment: I assumed it because without it I can't prove b=infV

Comment: You cannot always show that $b=\inf V$ whenever $b$ is a lower bound of $V$. For the example I gave in the comments, clearly, $0=\inf V$, not $-1$, though $-1$ is indeed a lower bound of $V$. Is this the doubt you wanted to clear or am I missing something?

Comment: I have changed my proof. In the exercise they say that b is a lower bound of V I only need to prove that b=infV. This is what i am trying to do but i'm not certain i am doing it right.

Comment: Can you post the exercise maybe it will make the problem clearer.

Comment: Oh, the question, asks you to show equivalence. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists u\in V\cap [b,b+\epsilon[$, $u\ge b\forall b\in V$, i.e. $b$ is a lower bound of $V$, and we cannot find an $ \epsilon >0$ such that $b+\epsilon=\inf V$ since $\exists v\in V$ such that $v<b+\epsilon$. Hence $b=\inf V$.